# Import Requests Error

Tags: import, request

I am starting to use requests lib and beautifulsoup lib. My goal is to extract data from Twitter, and do some hot topic analysis.

After I installed Python 2.7.5 on windows 7 system, I can import urllib2, but I can not import requests or BeautifulSoup.

Here is the error message below. Can someone help me here?

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:43:36) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32 Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import requests

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import requests ImportError: No module named requests
```

I have googled a lot but find little hint on my situation. If you think that more info is needed to solve the problem, please leave a note here, I will be more than glad to provide the info that's needed.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: you tried pip install requests?

Comment: @Abhishek, would you mind providing more details about pip? As far as I know, I haven't installed it on my PC. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem.

Mac OSX, IDLE Python 3.6:

Installed the module requests using the following commands:

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","--user","requests"])
```

The result was:

> Successfully installed requests-2.12.4

But then I could not import the module requests using the command "import requests". But also not the command "import requests-2.12.4" was running in the IDLE. Running on a shell starting with "python3" I could run the standard import command "import requests" successfully.

So I did quit the IDLE and started it new. And then it did run as expected.

Maybe this helps you too!

Comment: Not yet. Thank you for answering my old question.